# Why is the LastName field required for the contact? What is the best approach to import contacts that only have the first name?

Tags: contact, required-field, data-import

The reason for this question is that I have a spreadsheet with lots of contacts to import, but some of them only have the first name. The `LastName`, being mandatory, will make my job harder.

I have seen people switching the `FirstName` and `LastName` labels so that the first name is mandatory for the user (but on the API, the user is filling the last name), but that seems to be a bad workaround to me.

What would be the best practice to import contacts that do not have the last name? Put something generic on the field?

Comment: I have seen elsewhere people use `LNU` which represents `Last Name Unknown`. Salesforce [doesn't have any plan](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrPPAA0) to remove this validation from last name.

Comment: That sounds reasonable enough, actually.  UND ("Último Nome Desconhecido", in Portuguese) sounds good.

Comment: Please answer the question! I'll happily accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the `LastName` being mandatory, I can only say that it's by design. And seems there [were ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrPPAA0) to get it optional, but Salesforce doesn't have any plan to do so. So it is very unlikely we can get away with it.

As for the workaround, as you have noted you can either switch the `FirstName` to the `LastName`

OR

I have seen people using a notion `LNU` which represents Last Name Unknown (or `UND` Último Nome Desconhecido in Portuguese :) ) to populate the `LastName` field. I have also seen this used widely with some Organizations when people don't have a valid Last Name.

One other approach that I have seen around especially with Government Authorities where Last Name is always required, they use the approach of populating the First Name as Last Name and then using `FNU` for the First Name which represents First Name Unknown. (I have had a personal experience with this)

So as long as you have a way to identify such records, you can go with any of these approaches.

Comment: Brilliant workaround, reminds me of a former colleague in previous company having name as firstname.lnu@company.com

Comment: @Raul I have also seen another approach on this especially with government authorities where say Last Name is always required and that a person doesn't have one but only First Name, they will use the First Name as Last Name and then have the First Name referred as FNU (First Name Unknown).